# How to create a clickable link in a command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to get a command block to open up Netflix when i activate it. If the link is "https://www.netflix.com/browse", then what should the command be?
P.S. I want the text to be red and not underlined.

Comment: I'd recommend something like a tellraw generator like this one [here](http://minecraft.tools/en/tellraw.php) which is quite easy to use and it'll do all the magic for you.  It's simpler and you can see the limitations.

Answer (score 2):

I think that

```
/tellraw @p ["",{"text":"my text","color":"red","bold":true,"underlined":false,"clickEvent":{"action":"open_url","value":"https://www.netflix.com/browse"}}]
```

should do what you're asking for. When the player clicks the text, a menu pops up, saying "Are you sure you want to open the following website: https://www.netflix.com/browse Never open links from people you don't trust"
and 3 options: Yes, No and Copy to clipboard. If they click Yes, Netflix will be opened in their internet browser (possibly incompatible with some browsers), Copy to Clipboard copies it to their clipboard (and returns them to the game), No closes the menu.

Answer (score -2):

This *just* might work.

> /tellraw @p {"text":"Click here to go to Netflix!","color":"red","underlined":"false","clickEvent":{"action":"open_url","value":"https://www.netflix.com/browse"}}]

Answer (score -3):

```
/tellraw @p ["",{"text":"Click here to go to netflix browse!","color":"red","underlined":"false","clickEvent":{"action":"open_url","value":"https://www.netflix.com/browse"}},""]
```